# Interaction between 2 selected select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, onchange

I received data from MySql into both select2.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 kod_gecis">  
  <select name="p_code" id="p_code" class="form-control kod_ara">
<?php
foreach ($result4 as $row3) {
  echo '<option data-pname="' . $row3['ProductName'] . '" value="' . $row3['ProductCode'] . '">'
    . $row3['ProductCode']
    . '</option>';
}
?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 border border-warning gecis">
  <select name="p_name" id="p_name" class="form-control urun_ara">
<?php
foreach ($result2 as $row) {
  echo '<option data-pcode="' . $row['ProductCode'] . '" data-inbox="' . $row['PiecesInBox'] . '" data-price="' . $row['Price'] . '" name="' . $row['ProductName'] . '" value="' . $row['ProductName'] . '">'
    . $row['ProductName']
    . '</option>';
}
?>
  </select>
</div>
```

When I'm trying to select `p_name`, its going to change `p_code` select2 very well.
But the problem is for secondary one. I would be change to `p_name` while according to selected value of `p_code`.
This could be work like this:
Receives value from `p_code` selected value of `data-pname`, after then it should be equals to `p_name` value and search it.
Because some inputs works according to `p_name` change function.
Those both codes are working under document ready function.

```
$('#p_name').change(function() {
  var pcode = $('#p_name option:selected').data('pcode');
  $('#p_code').val(pcode).trigger("change");
});
$('#p_code').change(function() {
  var pname = $('#p_code option:selected').data('pname');
  $('#p_name').val(pname).trigger("change"); // it's not working
  $('#p_name').select2('');
});
```

Comment: Is your problem in the last line with `$('#p_name').select2('');`?

Comment: My problem in the p_code change function. It could be receive data from selected p_code and it should be check from p_name select2 values and should be search it. Because im using p_name change functions for the other inputs. So that mean im using data attributes of p_name while selected.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$('#p_name').select2('');` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. And im going to share for who needs to use interaction between 2 selected select2.

You should do for first function with

> change function

like this:

```
$('#p_name').change(function(){
    var pcode = $('#p_name option:selected').data('pcode');
    $('#p_code').val(pcode).trigger("change");
    });
```

For secondary one, you should use to

> 'select2:select'

function in order to get your first select2 selected value from data according to your data attribute and instantly select your secondary selected value.

**The working code is below (for the secondary select2):**

```
$('#p_code').on('select2:select', function () {
    var data = $('#p_code option:selected').data('pname');
$('#p_name').val(data).trigger('change');
});
```